# Android improve performance of layout with EditText

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I want to improve performance of `et_note_desc_value` EditText because when there is more characters, then typing here starts to be very laggy. How to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/root_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/b_ok"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_root"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:id="@+id/motion_layout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/new_edit_note_activity_scene">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_note_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/note_title"
                android:textColor="?attr/myTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_show_all"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/eye"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/show_all_fields" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/sv_note_title_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_show_all"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_note_title_value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top|start"
                    android:hint="@string/enter_title"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:maxLength="100"
                    android:textColor="?attr/myTextColor"
                    android:textColorHint="?attr/myHintTextColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </ScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_note_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/note_desc"
                android:textColor="?attr/myTextColor"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ScrollView
                android:id="@+id/sv_note_desc_value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_note_desc">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_note_desc_value"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:hint="@string/enter_desc"
                    android:maxLength="9000"
                    android:textColor="?attr/myTextColor"
                    android:textColorHint="?attr/myHintTextColor"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

            </ScrollView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/b_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/rl_ad_wrapper"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/c_2196f3"
        android:text="@android:string/ok"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_ad_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ad_wrapper_border">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="?attr/myTextColorInverted"
            android:text="@string/ad"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think there is something on your code (a listener, a callback, a TextWatcher, etc...) that makes an EditText laggy.